# List with limited item

Tags: c#, list, generics, queue

I need to keep a short history of values. So I need a list with a maximum number of items. And I want it to accept new addition even when it's full. In that case I want the oldest item I added to be lost.
I did not find any class suiting this purpose then did my own. I will certainly add methods later on but for now I have what I need.

So my first question to you is: Is it a correct code: http://pastebin.com/0BCbyNqJ
Does that class look clean enough to you?

And my second question is about these exceptions I am throwing.

```
/// <summary>
/// Oldest item added to the list
/// </summary>
public T First
{
    get
    {
        if (_head < 0)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("The list is empty");

        if (_firstRoundDone)
            return _array[(_head + 1) % _max];
        else
            return _array[0];
    }
}
```

Before anything is added to my list, I would like calls to `First`, `Last` and `Count`to return null. I think that would make more sense. But I don't know how to do so since the return types are int or T, for which I don't want to add a constraint like `where T:Nullable`.
As I don't see any solution I wonder if the Exception is not, afterall, the most elegant way. Or should I implement methods like `GetFirst(out T first)` or even `TryGetFirst(out T)`?

Comment: Seems like maybe a Queue would be more suitable?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx

Comment: You could always return `default(T)` instead of null...

Comment: @dbaseman a queue is just a fifo collection, it doesn't have a limited capacity like a LRU cache

Comment: A queue would probably be a more suitable internal data structure for this, rather than an array.

Comment: A Queue does not have a capacity cap as I want to have a history- or cache- behavior

Comment: @Spontifixus That's is another alternative but it does not sound like what you expect to be return if a value your are asking for does not exists

Comment: (But I did not think about a clever implementation as proposed by Alex!)

Comment: @Mr.Pe, that's right I just wanted to hint in that direction - in case that it helps ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Extending `Queue<>` would produce a very short code, like this:

```
public class Buffer<T> : Queue<T>
{
    private int? maxCapacity { get; set; }

    public Buffer() { maxCapacity = null; }
    public Buffer(int capacity) { maxCapacity = capacity; }

    public void Add(T newElement)
    {
        if (this.Count == (maxCapacity ?? -1)) this.Dequeue(); // no limit if maxCapacity = null
        this.Enqueue(newElement);
    }
}
```

`.Clear()` and `.ToList()` would be inherited, no need to implement them.

Comment: I should downgrade you to make me look stupid. Thanks for this clever solution.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that for the thread-safeness of a `Queue<>` a `Synchronized` method is provided in order to obtain a thread-safe wrapper (MSDN has all the info, including the growth ratio: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Consider publicly available LRU caches such as http://code.google.com/p/csharp-lru-cache/.

Comment: Thank you, that looks very nice code. But it is a bit of an overkill for my present small need. I see though that it throws an exception for cases as I described. Very interesting.

Comment: @Mr.Pe Using third party code will allow you to focus on other parts of your application and may help you as you scale up when you meet other problems the third party code may already solve. However, there may be more to it and it is your decision.

Comment: You are right. But it can also bring unexpected behaviors. This is here for a pretty small purpose, a history of no more than 20 items. Which lead me to think that would be better to use a concise, yet generic, solution.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds as if what you want is a Queue. This, however, [is already provided in .Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx). You should probably use that, and the methods it provides.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a circular buffer that allows overflow. Such an implementation can be [found here](http://circularbuffer.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thank you, that looks very nice code. But it is a bit of an overkill for my present small need. I see though that it throws an exception for cases as I described. Very interesting.